GitLab CI: Conditionally run job steps based on file changes
I'm working with GitLab CI and I have a job template that I want to modify. Currently, my job looks like this:
mwaa:dags:test:2.8.1:
  variables:
    AIRFLOW_VERSION: 2.8.1
    PYTHON_VERSION: 3.11
  extends:
    - .template_MWAA:DAGS:Test

This job extends a template that includes before_script, script, and after_script sections. I want to modify the job so that:

If there are changes in the airflow-mwaa/requirements/** directory, it should run all sections (before_script, script, and after_script).
If there are no changes in the airflow-mwaa/requirements/** directory, it should only run the script section.

Here are the relevant parts of the template:
before_script:
  - echo "Starting .install_dependencies template"
  - pip3 install -r "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/airflow-mwaa/requirements/$AIRFLOW_VERSION/requirements.txt"

script:
  - echo "Starting .template_MWAA:DAGS:Test template"
  - cd "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/airflow-mwaa"
  - airflow db init
  - ./tests-ci.sh

after_script:
  # remove older files from terraform providers cache
  - find "$PIP_CACHE_DIR" -mindepth 1 -mtime +14 -type f -delete
  - find "$PIP_CACHE_DIR" -mindepth 1 -mtime +14 -type d -empty -delete

  stage: Test
  extends:
    - .template_MWAA
  needs: []
  variables:
    PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"
    PYTHONPATH: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/airflow-mwaa/dags"
  cache:
    key: $CI_JOB_NAME_SLUG-python
    paths:
      - .cache/pip
  before_script:
    - echo "Starting .install_dependencies template"
    - pip3 install -r "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/airflow-mwaa/requirements/$AIRFLOW_VERSION/requirements.txt"
  script:
    - echo "Starting .template_MWAA:DAGS:Test template"
    - cd "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/airflow-mwaa"
    - airflow db init
    - ./tests-ci.sh
  after_script:
    # remove older files from terraform providers cache
    - find "$PIP_CACHE_DIR" -mindepth 1 -mtime +14 -type f -delete
    - find "$PIP_CACHE_DIR" -mindepth 1 -mtime +14 -type d -empty -delete
  coverage: '/^TOTAL\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(\d+\%)$/'
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/airflow-mwaa/test_results/report.xml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true"
      when: on_success
      allow_failure: false
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      changes:
        - airflow-mwaa/dags/**/*
        - airflow-mwaa/tests/**/*
      allow_failure: false
      when: on_success
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true
    - when: never

How can I modify my job or template to achieve this conditional execution based on file changes? I'm not sure how to combine the changes condition with selective execution of script sections.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I think something like this could work:
# Single job just to generate a CHANGE_DETECTED variable
# See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv
change_detection:
  rules:
    - changes:
        - airflow-mwaa/requirements/**
      variables:
        CHANGE_DETECTED: "true"
    - variables:
        CHANGE_DETECTED: "false"
  script:
    - echo "$CHANGE_DETECTED" > change_detection.env
  artifacts:
    report:
      dotenv: change_detection.env

.mwaa:dags:test:2.8.1:
  variables:
    AIRFLOW_VERSION: 2.8.1
    PYTHON_VERSION: 3.11
  needs:
    - change_detection # Here we get the CHANGE_DETECTED variable
  extends:
    - .template_MWAA:DAGS:Test

mwaa:dags:test:2.8.1_unchanged:
  extends:
    - .mwaa:dags:test:2.8.1
  # Override the before and after script by empty arrays 
  # to not run those for this job:
  before_script: []
  after_script: []
  rules:
    - if: $CHANGE_DETECTED == "true"
      when: never # Invert the rule to stop processing next rules
    - !reference [.template_MWAA:DAGS:Test, rules]

mwaa:dags:test:2.8.1_changed:
  extends:
    - .mwaa:dags:test:2.8.1
  rules:
    - if: $CHANGE_DETECTED == "false"
      when: never
    - !reference [.template_MWAA:DAGS:Test, rules]

But you almost end up with more YAML than just copy pasting the original template and do the small changes there, which might actually end up more readable (at a slight DRY cost).
I have assumed that changes to the template was constrained (owned by someone else, imported from somewhere, etc.), but if you can alter the template it all becomes easier, as you could just use the variable in the bash script parts and do things like:
  before_script:
    - |
      if [ "$CHANGE_DETECTED" == "true" ]; then
        echo "Starting .install_dependencies template"
        pip3 install -r "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/airflow-mwaa/requirements/$AIRFLOW_VERSION/requirements.txt"
      fi

